# How to create a leaf file using jstree 3.0.0?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I tree seems to work but can't create a leaf file but it does seems to create folder file

```
Here's the code the I can't seem to get to work when creating a leaf node:


$("#createLeafFile").on("click", function(event)
{
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();

      var $tableRef = $("#tableTree").jstree(tree);
      var $selectedNode = $tableRef.get_selected();

      if(!$selectedNode)
      {
         return false;
      }
      $selectedNode = selectedNode[0];
      $selectedNode = $tableRef.create_node($selectedNode, {"type": "file"});
      if($selectedNode)
      {
         $tableRef.edit($selectedNode);
      }    
});
```

This code works but can't create a leaf node that shows a file icon. How would I create the above node with an associated leaf file icon. Somehow it shows a folder file icon. Also, when I click on this new node, after highlighting it, it creates children nodes under it. This is not what I want when creating a leaf file...

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the tree, did you set `"check_callback" : true`?

The demo at jsTree works for me.  [jsTree Demo](http://www.jstree.com/demo/)

Comment: Yes HDoan, i have check_callback : true set when loading the tree... Any other suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I check the jsTree demo and notice when they retrieve the jsTree its like 
`var $tableRef = $("#tableTree").jstree(true);`.
But yours is `var $tableRef = $("#tableTree").jstree(tree);`.
Perhaps try change tree to true?